# Do function pointer addresses hold after conversions?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, function-pointers, reinterpret-cast

From what I understand, casting function pointers to different types is allowed by the C++ standard (as long as one never invokes them):

```cpp
int my_func(int v) { return v; }

int main() {
    using from_type = int(int);
    using to_type = void(void);

    from_type *from = &my_func;
    to_type *to = reinterpret_cast<to_type *>(from);

    // ...
}
```

Moreover, there is no undefined behavior if I cast the pointer back to its original type and invoke it.

So far, so good. What about the following, then?

```cpp
const bool eq = (to == reinterpret_cast<to_type *>(my_func));
```

Does the address hold, too, after the conversion, or is this not guaranteed by the standard?

---

While this is irrelevant to the question, a possible scenario is when one goes hard on type erasure. If the address holds, something can be done without having to know the original function type.

Comment: Actually, it is not @AdrianMole I'm not asking about comparing plain function pointers here. I'm asking if the address holds after a function pointer conversion. The _comparing_ part is just to make it clear what I mean.

Comment: Also, the answer to my question is very likely "no" but no spoiler. This makes even more unlikely the dup call. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [[expr.reinterpret.cast].6](https://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#6) (emphasis mine):

> A function pointer can be explicitly converted to a function pointer of a different type.
> [...]
>
> Except that converting a prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type
> “pointer to T2” (where T1 and T2 are function types) and back to its
> original type yields the original pointer value, **the result of such a
> pointer conversion is unspecified.**

So, the standard explicitly allows casting function pointers to different FP types and then back. This is an exception to the general rule that `reinterpret_cast`ing function pointers is *unspecified*.

In my understanding, that means `to == reinterpret_cast<to_type *>(my_func)` need not necessarily be `true`.

Comment: Due to the _is unspecified_ token. It makes sense, even if it's damned unfortunate. :(

Comment: @skypjack The standard probably leaves a lot of leeway to the compiler intentionally, but I can't imagine any reasonable implementation strategy where it won't hold. I don't think it has any practical relevance. `reinterpret_cast` also can't be used in constant expressions, so it is not a concern for the validity of those either.

Comment: I agree that it's hard to see a possible use but still, I don't want to rely on an _it's a safe UB_ policy in my production code. You know. :)